# Parallel http requests take the same amount of time

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient, parallel.foreach

It takes a lot of time execute my program and 99% of it is sending request and waiting for response (the url is the same for all requests). That's why I want to send multiple http requests and currently I am using HttpClient.

Basically, my code looks like this:

```
Parallel.Foreach(objects, async obj => {
    //create content
    var client = new HttpClient {Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1, 0)};
    var response = await client.PostAsync(url, stringContent);
    //do something with response
});
```

However the program still takes almost the same amount of time.
I tried adding in Main:

```
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 100;
```

I also changed the line:

```
Parallel.ForEach(objects, parallelOptions: new ParallelOptions{MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2}, body: async obj =>
```

Visual Studio shows that indeed 2 threads are created, but still time is the same.

I also want to point out that I had to make Timeout big enough becase otherwise there was TaskCanceledException.

Comment: **1.** Read this: https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/ - only use a single instance of HttpClient. It's in MS docs that you should use a static instance of HttpClient. **2.** You should build a list of Tasks (i.e. `list.Add(client.PostAsync(url, stringContent);`) and then wait for them `await Task.WhenAll(list);` in a single place.

Comment: Not quite related to the actual issue, but still: https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Comment: I will definitely remember it, however it doesn't fix my problem. Even worse, with one HttpClient after sending around 1900 requests I start getting error that says that my StringContent is disposed.

Comment: @ettudagny " my StringContent is disposed" - That's a problem with your code, not with HttpClient. The StringContent needs to live for the life of the request.  If you want a proper answer, I recommend creating an [mcve] so that we can test it.